# PHP MySQL select BLOB from DB_1 and insert into DB_2

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, blob

I am trying to migrate attachments (stored as longBLOB in DB. I know it's a bad idea but we are thinking about migrate files into a fileSystem later on) from DB_1 to DB_2. I wrote basic mysql query to select all the fields from DB_1 and trying to insert into DB_2. I can successfully echo all the data on the page but the insertion doesn't work.

```
 $conn1 = new mysqli($HOST1,$USER1,$PASS1,$NAME1,$PORT1); //DB1
 $conn2 = new mysqli($HOST2,$USER2,$PASS2,$NAME2,$PORT2); //DB2

 *//`filedata` is the longBLOB field in table `file_chunk`. *
 *//Other info like file name, file size, key, signature and etc. *
 *//are stored in another table named `file` associated with `file_chunk` by* 
 *//the field `file_id'.*

 $stmt = $conn1->prepare("SELECT c.chunk_id, c.filedata FROM 
 ".$prefix."_file_chunk c WHERE c.file_id = ?");
 $stmt->bind_param("i", $fid);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->bind_result($trans_fileChunk);

 if($trans_fileChunk->num_rows > 0){
    $row_file_chunk = mysqli_fetch_array($trans_fileChunk);
    $null = NULL;
    $n_filedata = mysqli_real_escape_string($row_file_chunk['filedata']);
    $stmt = $conn2->prepare("INSERT INTO cp_file_chunk (file_id, chunk_id, 
    filedata) VALUES (?,?,?)");
*//$n_file_id = current max(id) + 1;* 
    $stmt->bind_param("iib", $n_file_id, $row_file_chunk['chunk_id'], $null);
    $stmt->send_long_data(2, $n_filedata);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

When I run this code, I can see the file appears on DB_2 (probably because the `file` table was migrated correctly), but when I tried to download this file from chrome, it shows "Failed". I am sure this file didn't exceed the `max_allowed_packet'. I am guessing there are errors during the "SELECT" BLOB and "INSERT" BLOB processes. Could someone help me with this? Much appreciate it!

Comment: How large is the average file?

Comment: @MasonStedman I have set the max to be 2 mb. The file I used for testing was 798 kb.

Comment: There's other issues such as script timeout settings and max POST size (different than max file size) that can be a factor as well, which is why I asked.  I assume those are both set appropriately as well since you didn't bother including them in your question/reply.

Comment: @MasonStedman Sorry I didn't mention those. I think I found the issue, the open source I am using has set that all the attachment stored in the database are cut into 500KB chunks. I tried with different files smaller than 500kb and worked. Now my questions is how can I insert the blob data in chunks of 500kb? Thank you!